# Laravel pagination with raw

Tags: laravel, pagination

I just want to ask about something related to laravel pagination. 
I have this line of code
`DB::select(DB::raw('my query here'));` in my controller but I want to paginate the result of this query. Is it possible?

Update: This is my actual code.

```
  $query = "SELECT
                * 
            FROM
                bil_tbl_billing_service_item AS bil_service_item
                INNER JOIN bil_tbl_billing AS billing ON billing.ID = bil_service_item.billing_id

                INNER JOIN dblink
                ('pofsis_business', 
                'SELECT
                        service_item.id as service_item_id,
                        service_item.series_num as service_item_series_num,
                        service_item.name as service_item_name,
                        service_item.particular as service_item_particular,
                        service_item.amount as service_item_amount,
                        vat_type.type as service_item_vat_type,
                        vat_type.rate as service_item_vat_rate
                    FROM
                        biz_tbl_service_item AS service_item
                        INNER JOIN biz_tbl_service_item_other as service_item_other on service_item_other.service_item_id = service_item.id
                        INNER JOIN biz_tbl_vat_type as vat_type on vat_type.id = service_item_other.type_of_vat_id') as service_item (service_item_id INTEGER, service_item_series_num VARCHAR, service_item_name VARCHAR, service_item_particular VARCHAR, service_item_amount NUMERIC, service_item_vat_type VARCHAR, service_item_vat_rate INTEGER) ON service_item.service_item_id = bil_service_item.service_item_id

                WHERE billing.active = 1";
    if($billingId !== null) {
        $query = $query." AND billing.id = $billingId";
    }
    return db::select(db::raw($query));
```

Comment: can you change it to query builder and run

Comment: put your sql query here

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post. Do you think I can do it using query builder?

Answer (score -1):

If query is working correctly and giving you the result

Do like this for pagination

```
DB::select(DB::raw('my query here'))->paginate(10);
```

Comment: It gives me this error 'Call to a member function paginate() on array'.